# asp calendar : blocking off when navigating previous/ next month

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, calendar

i'm using asp calendar in my webpage, when i was clicking the previous month arrow its just showing that month and popping off. but if its month navigation it should display as per my requirement ? and its selection date it should pop off.

Below is my code :

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.GIF" Width="20px"    onclick="displayCalendar()"  />
<div id="datePicker"><asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" ></asp:Calendar></div>

function displayCalendar() {
    var datePicker = document.getElementById('datePicker');
    datePicker.style.display = 'block';
}

protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("d");
    }
```

anyone's help will be appreciated .

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my solution for this question.

```
OnsivibleMonthChanged="<function()>"
```

calendar control.

and defining the function to display the calendar.