# ASP Calendar not showing data for previous and next month

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP Calendar Page that pulls an event list from a database. The issue that I am having is that data is shown for the current month but not for the previous and next months when I click on the next and previous months. Does ASP Calendar reload the entire page when a different month is clicked or does it act as a query string property?

Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
protected DataSet dsEvents;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calendar1.FirstDayOfWeek = FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday;
    Calendar1.NextPrevFormat = NextPrevFormat.FullMonth;
    Calendar1.TitleFormat = TitleFormat.Month;
    Calendar1.ShowGridLines = true;
    Calendar1.DayStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
    Calendar1.DayStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
    Calendar1.OtherMonthDayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;

    Calendar1.VisibleDate = DateTime.Today;
    FillEventDataset();
    GetFirstDayOfNextMonth();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Calendar1.VisibleDate = DateTime.Today;
        FillEventDataset();
        GetFirstDayOfNextMonth();
    }
}

protected DateTime GetFirstDayOfNextMonth()
{
    int monthNumber, yearNumber;
    if (Calendar1.VisibleDate.Month == 12)
    {
        monthNumber = 1;
        yearNumber = Calendar1.VisibleDate.Year + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        monthNumber = Calendar1.VisibleDate.Month + 1;
        yearNumber = Calendar1.VisibleDate.Year;
    }
    DateTime lastDate = new DateTime(yearNumber, monthNumber, 1);
    return lastDate;
}

protected void FillEventDataset()
{
    DateTime firstDate = new DateTime(Calendar1.VisibleDate.Year, Calendar1.VisibleDate.Month, 1);
    DateTime lastDate = GetFirstDayOfNextMonth();
    dsEvents = GetSelectedMonthData(firstDate, lastDate);
}

protected DataSet GetSelectedMonthData(DateTime firstDate, DateTime lastDate)
{
    DataSet dsMonth = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT EventDate, EventLocation, EventSubject, EventStart FROM EventList WHERE EventDate >= @FirstDate AND EventDate <= @LastDate", conn);

        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstDate", firstDate);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastDate", lastDate);

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        try
        {
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dsMonth);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    return dsMonth;
}

protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
    e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    if (e.Day.IsOtherMonth)
    {
        e.Cell.Visible = true;
        e.Cell.Text = "";
    }

    DateTime nextEvent;
    String nextLocation;
    String nextSubject;
    String nextStart;

    if (dsEvents != null)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dsEvents.Tables[0].Rows)
        {

            nextEvent = (DateTime)dr["EventDate"];
            nextLocation = dr["EventLocation"].ToString();
            nextSubject = dr["EventSubject"].ToString();
            nextStart = dr["EventStart"].ToString();

            if (nextEvent == e.Day.Date)
            {
                Literal literal1 = new Literal();
                literal1.Text = "<br/>";
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(literal1);

                Label label1 = new Label();
                label1.Text = nextStart.ToString();
                label1.Font.Size = new FontUnit(FontSize.Small);
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(label1);

                Literal literal2 = new Literal();
                literal2.Text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(literal2);

                Label label2 = new Label();
                label2.Text = nextSubject.ToString();
                label2.Font.Size = new FontUnit(FontSize.Small);
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(label2);

                Literal literal3 = new Literal();
                literal3.Text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(literal3);

                Label label3 = new Label();
                label3.Text = nextLocation.ToString();
                label3.Font.Size = new FontUnit(FontSize.Small);
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(label3);
            }

        }
    }
}

protected void Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender, MonthChangedEventArgs e)
{
    GetFirstDayOfNextMonth();
    FillEventDataset();
}
```

Comment: Any chance you are running with `EnableViewState="false"` on page level or `ViewStateMode="Disabled"` on the `Calendar` control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested your entire code. It works just fine. But at first load it executes the code twice.

```
//remove these two lines
FillEventDataset();
GetFirstDayOfNextMonth();

if (!IsPostBack)
{
    Calendar1.VisibleDate = DateTime.Today;
    FillEventDataset();
    GetFirstDayOfNextMonth();
}
```

To view if the correct months are used, add this line to the `GetSelectedMonthData` method.

```
Label1.Text = firstDate.ToLongDateString() + " - " + lastDate.ToLongDateString();
```

If the months displayed there are correct there is most likely a problem with the dates in the database. But just to make sure... You did add the events to the Calendar Control?

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender"
  OnVisibleMonthChanged="Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged"></asp:Calendar>
```

To be extra sure, it is better to change `AddWithValue` to

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@FirstDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = firstDate;
comm.Parameters.Add("@LastDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = lastDate;
```

Comment: I used your onVisibleMonthChanged suggestion and when I click on a previous or following month it shows as 1/1/0001 which is a null value.

Comment: Debug the code and see why it is wrong. Like I said it worked when I tested it.You can use that trick with the Label to see where it is going wrong if you do not know how to debug in Visual Studio. But then again it gets the dates from the Calendar itself so it is strange that they are wrong...

Comment: Made any progress?

Answer (score 0):

> Does ASP Calendar reload the entire page when a different month is clicked or does it act as a query string property?

Yes, the problem is the Postback, what you cannot avoid.

Since I have several calendars, I have made it general

Foo.aspx

```
  <asp:Calendar ID="cal1" runat="server" OnVisibleMonthChanged="cal_VisibleMonthChanged" [...]/>

  <asp:Calendar ID="cal2" runat="server" OnVisibleMonthChanged="cal_VisibleMonthChanged" [...]/>

  <asp:Calendar ID="cal3" runat="server" OnVisibleMonthChanged="cal_VisibleMonthChanged" [...]/>
```

Foo.aspx.cs

```
protected void cal_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender, MonthChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Calendar)sender).Visible = true;
}
```

This posting was helpful (for me)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25750717/15274506